# Will This Code Work on Other Windows Versions?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

The following batch file works on my version of windows (10) but will it work on windows 7 or 8?

```
@echo off
title 
color a
mode con cols=20 lines=10 >null
mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("msgbox ""Error while opening."",5+64,""Error"":close")
mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("msgbox ""A virus has been detected. Would you like to run a scan?"",0+48,""Virus"":close")
mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("msgbox ""Access denied. Launching virus."",2+16,""You Have Been Infected"":close")
start call "juices"
start call "juices"
mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("msgbox ""Deleting core files..."",2+16,""Removing"":close")
start call "juices2"
start call "jxt295"
start call "jxt295"
start call "jxt295"
start call "jxt295" 
call "shdwn"
```

Comment: This question belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Before we clarify other versions of Windows, does it even work on Windows 10? Doesn't look like.

Comment: Thomas, it does, I tested it.

Comment: @NikoGill: no, you tested it on *your windows environment*. It will not run on a standard Windows (any version).

Comment: There are two versions of CMD - NT4 and earlier and Win2000 and later. So the current CMD has been around for 16 years. Any reference in help to new behaviour is how the Windows 2000 version differs from the NT4 version.

Comment: How can anyone tell whether it works or not without knowing what the script is intended for? By the way, change `>null` to `>nul` to not create a file called `null.`...

Answer (score 4):

Line two looks like a pointless inclusion as no title is included.

Line 3 only provides the text color but fails to check what color it is actually set to or if that color is already set as the background color.

Line 4 may not be correct in any version of Windows but that depends if you are intending to output to an extensionless file named null!

Lines 5, 6 & 7 wont actually do anything and will present buttons which also achieve nothing.

Lines 8 & 9 appear identical for no obvious reason and use both start and call also for no obvious reason they also fail to use double quotes correctly with the start command. They may also not work if %PATHEXT% doesn't reference the required extension of juices.

Line 10 exhibits the same issues as lines 5, 6 & 7.

Line 11 uses both call and start for no obvious reason and once again fails to use double quotes correctly with the start command. It may also not work if %PATHEXT% doesn't reference the required extension of juices2.

Lines 12, 13, 14, & 15 exhibit the same issues as lines 8 & 9, and may also not work if %PATHEXT% doesn't reference the required extension of jxt295.

Line 16 may not work if %PATHEXT% doesn't reference the required extension of shdwn.

But to answer your question, **line 1 should work fine in your target OS's**!